# Azure Devops Pipeline Test step fails - incorrect path to data files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a Repo containing three solutions.  Each solution has multiple projects, many of which are shared (including test projects).

I have a build pipeline along the following lines

- Retrieve NuGet packages
- Build Solution 1
- Build Solution 2
- Build Solution 3
- Execute all tests

The step to execute all tests is as follows:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test'
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

The vast majority of tests run perfectly.  However, I get the odd and rather confusing error message for some tests:

> [error]SetUp failed for test fixture TestProjectOne.A.B.GetSomethingTests
>
> [error]SetUp : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path
>   'd:\a\1\s\Projects\TestProjectTwo\A\B\TestData\SomeFile.txt'.

So it's currently processing **TestProjectOne** but then saying it can't find a file under a path for **TestProjectTwo**.

The code within the test is as follows:

```
private const string RelativePath = @"..\..\A\B\TestData\";
...
var x = File.ReadAllText(RelativePath + "SomeFile.txt")
```

Needless to say, this works perfectly using Visual Studio 2019 using both the Visual Studio and ReSharper test runner.

Why would an Azure DevOps pipeline suffer this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would an Azure DevOps pipeline suffer this issue?

That because we use wildcard in the VS test task:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test'
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
```

Which will grab all `*test*.dll` files in the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` folder, including the sub folder.

Obviously, the great convenience brought by this method is that we do not have to grab the `*test*.dll` from the folder one by one. **But one problem with it is that since we are using wildcards, it will lose the full path of the each `*test*.dll` file**. In thise case, if we specify the relative path `..\..\A\B\TestData\` in the `*test*.dll` file, it will not get the correct path, because the current `*test*.dll` file lost its full path.

That is reason why it execute the test dll from `TestProjectOne.A.B.GetSomethingTests`, but got the path from `TestProjectTwo`.

To resolve this issue, we could specify the full path in the `*test*.dll` file instead of the relative path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bit of additional info, I used a single task for all 14 of our test projects.  For the property `testAssemblyVer2` I added the path to each DLL, separated by the pipe delimiter.  Took me a while to get the path correct, but it follows: `A\B.Test\bin\Release\B.Test.dll`